# Oracle: Why do I have to use TO_DATE to pull my data?

Tags: oracle, to-date

When trying to filter on EXPIRE_DATE, it seems I have to use TO_DATE. Why do I have to use TO_DATE? The **EXPIRE_DATE** data type in the database is ALREADY set to date. Here is the code that works.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE EXPIRE_DATE >= TO_DATE('2020/01/13','yyyy/mm/dd')
  AND EXPIRE_DATE <= TO_DATE('2020/04/19','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

I tried to use BETWEEN without TO_DATE and just use my dates but I received an error.

To recap, even though the data type for this is ALREADY date, it seems I have to use TO_DATE to pull my data when I want to filter. Is there something I am missing? Here is my error when I try filter my data without using TO_DATE.

[image: my error]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code that generates the error message. Its not constructive to give us the code that works and then tell us that when you do something different you get an error without telling us what the thing was that you did differently.

Comment: What is the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Oracle forces you to use TO_DATE around the expressions on the right-hand side. What does that have to do with the data type of the column on the **left**-hand side? Oracle is not making you use TO_DATE on EXPIRE_DATE, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from some good answers here, I would like to tell you that you do not need `TO_DATE` to pull the data from your table.

You need `to_date` or `date literal` to convert the normal string to date which can be compared to the column data in your table, As the date column must be compared with the date data type variable/constant.

To convert normal string to date, You can use the following:

```
TO_DATE('2020/01/13','yyyy/mm/dd')
DATE '2020-01-13'
```

I would not recommend using `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` just for creating the date.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `TO_DATE`, instead you can use a `DATE` literal:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   MY_TABLE
WHERE  EXPIRE_DATE >= DATE '2020/01/13'
AND    EXPIRE_DATE <= DATE '2020/04/19'
```

Or, if your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter matches `YYYY/MM/DD` then you can insert the values as strings and rely on implicit string conversion (don't do this though):

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY/MM/DD';

SELECT *
FROM   MY_TABLE
WHERE  EXPIRE_DATE >= '2020/01/13'
AND    EXPIRE_DATE <= '2020/04/19'
```

But it is not good practice to rely on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as **ANY** user can change their own value at **ANY** time so your query can randomly fail when users start changing these values.

Comment: but my question is why do I have to use DATE...why cant I Just use between and use my criteria?  Cant I just do it without any other functions?

Comment: Because Oracle is a strict type language. Just because you infer the sequence of characters '2020/01/13'  as a date Oracle does not it sees it as  just a string - due to the quotes('), The DATE or to_date functions tell Oracle how you want to process that  string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BETWEEN:

**Warning**: it's  better to use always **TO_DATE** function with proper format string and avoid implicit conversions that in some occasions produces strange behaviors in the results.

**Warning**: all columns of type DATE have always the hour-minute-second component.
if you forget this you may have fewer records in the result.

Example:

```
create table my_table
(id          number,
 expire_date date
);
```

Some data:

```
insert into my_table values ( 4,to_date('2011-06-17 10:07:18','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')); 
insert into my_table values (12,to_date('2010-10-01 17:43:30','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (13,to_date('2011-07-30 08:38:34','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (21,to_date('2010-04-22 07:03:35','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (26,to_date('2011-03-26 02:07:57','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (35,to_date('2010-09-16 17:40:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (38,to_date('2011-11-05 17:27:45','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (44,to_date('2011-12-25 04:51:24','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (45,to_date('2011-11-05 03:08:51','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (54,to_date('2011-09-22 18:29:14','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (78,to_date('2010-03-12 20:23:21','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (79,to_date('2011-05-19 17:30:15','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (83,to_date('2011-11-15 10:04:58','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into my_table values (96,to_date('2011-03-11 20:14:30','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Set default date format to ISO-8601 international format:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Query using implicit conversion:

```
SELECT a.*
fROM my_table a
where expire_date between '2010-01-01 00:00:00'
                      and '2010-12-31 23:59:59';
```

Answer:

```
ID EXPIRE_DATE        
12 2010-10-01 17:43:30
21 2010-04-22 07:03:35
35 2010-09-16 17:40:01
78 2010-03-12 20:23:21
```

but using US date format month-day-year:

```
SELECT a.*
fROM my_table a
where expire_date between '01/01/2010 00:00:00'
                      and '12/31/2010 23:59:59';
```

You got error:

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Change session date format to US format:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

you can write dates in US format:

```
SELECT a.*
fROM my_table a
where expire_date between '01/01/2010 00:00:00'
                      and '12/31/2010 23:59:59';
```

And the answer is:

```
        ID EXPIRE_DATE
---------- -------------------
        12 10-01-2010 17:43:30
        21 04-22-2010 07:03:35
        35 09-16-2010 17:40:01
        78 03-12-2010 20:23:21
```

Comment: But why do I have to use any literal? The data type is already DATE and its not a string. Sorry I should have asked my question better and I see you used exactly what I wanted to say. How come I cant use this query to pull my code 

"SELECT a.*
fROM my_table a
where expire_date between '2010-01-01 00:00:00'
                      and '2010-12-31 23:59:59'"     

 In this example there is no literal being used in the query. This is how I thought Oracle would let me do it but it doesnt.

Comment: Yes, there _IS_ a literal string.  Two of them in this example. '2010-01-01 00:00:00' and '2010-12-31 23:59:59'.  I think what you are missing is that a DATE data type is an internal, binary structure. And the _only_ thing you can enter at a keyboard is characters.  Now, _you_ may look at '2020-06-03' and think you see a date, but oracle just sees a string of characters.  You have to use to_date to tell oracle how to interpret that string, and convert it to its own, internal binary DATE format.  For more,see https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Comment: gotcha.. ok that makes more sense now. I was thinking this whole time oracle sees it as a date and NOT string.  very interesting, thank you for your response.

Comment: @EdStevens I agree with you,  DATE data type is a lot of source of confussion and bad programming. For example once  I see this : **SYSDATE<to_char( v_variable,'dd-mm-yyyy')**